# Get status of cancellation of my subscription in Combine iOS

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have this simple subscription where my `subject` is eminting strings. Just for curiosity I would like to know if my subscription is cancelled.

Afaik a pipeline that has been cancelled will not send any completions.
Are there some ways do achieve this?

The use case would be that I can cancel all subscriptions and receive a completion on this. Where I can clean up stuff a reflect this probably.

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var disposeBag: Set<AnyCancellable> = .init()

let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

subject.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    switch completion {
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Failed with: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    case .finished:
        print("Finished")
    }
}) { string in
    print(string)
}.store(in: &disposeBag)

subject.send("A")
disposeBag.map { $0.cancel() }
subject.send("B")
```

Comment: "The use case would be that I can cancel all subscriptions and receive a completion on this. Where I can clean up stuff a reflect this probably." I feel like this goes against the core principles of Combine. Publishers are not supposed to care whether they have subscribers. They should just _publish_. You should not clean things up just because there are no subscribers.

Comment: You are right, but I'm not talking about Publishers, but I mean subscriptions.  At the moment I `sink` I turned my Publisher to and subscriber.

Comment: Oh I see, so you want to know it in the `sink` closure.

Comment: What kind of cleanup would you do? There is no cancelled event in Combine unfortunately and the idea of doing cleanup in case of cancellation seems fishy as it's usually not needed. The publisher and subscription will take care of any cleanup they can do on their own already

Comment: @donnywals I agree tbh it's just curiosity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible via handling events

```
subject
    .handleEvents(receiveCancel: {
        print(">> cancelled")         // << here !!
    })
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Failed with: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        case .finished:
            print("Finished")
        }
    }) { string in
        print(string)
    }.store(in: &disposeBag)
```